# Exchange 2010 Powershell - Return Users With SendAs Permissions But Filter Disabled Users

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

so I have a script that works fine that I found online and changed to suit my needs. I have pasted this script below. However, in the output there is a lot of disabled users that have permissions to the mailboxes. E.g. I'd get an Output like "Mailbox Name^Mailbox@email.com^ActiveUser ActiveUser DisabledUser" So I am wondering if there is a way to make the script skip disabled users, same way how it leaves out self permissions.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
. $env:ExchangeInstallPath\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto

$OutFile = “C:\Send_As_Permissions.txt”
“DisplayName” + “^” + “Email Address” + “^” + “Send As” | Out-File $OutFile -Force
 
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | Select Identity, Alias, DisplayName, DistinguishedName, WindowsEmailAddress
ForEach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes) {
    $SendAs = Get-ADPermission $Mailbox.identity | where {($_.ExtendedRights -like “*Send-As*”) -and -not ($_.User -like “NT AUTHORITY\SELF”) -and -not ($_.User -like “s-1-5-21*”)} | % {$_.User}
    $Mailbox.DisplayName + “^” + $Mailbox.WindowsEmailAddress + “^” + $SendAs | Out-File $OutFile -Append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to report on enabled mailboxes only, filter the output from `Get-Mailbox` on the [`IsMailboxEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/ff324139(v=exchg.150)) property:

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | Where-Object { $_.IsMailboxEnabled } | Select ...
```

If you want to report on individual rights assignments for enabled accounts only, you'll have to query AD based on the value of the `User` property you extract:

```
$SendAs = Get-ADPermission $Mailbox.identity | where {($_.ExtendedRights -like “*Send-As*”) -and -not ($_.User -like “NT AUTHORITY\SELF”) -and -not ($_.User -like “s-1-5-21*”)} | % {$_.User}

$domain,$username = $SendAs.Split('\')
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Server $domain
if($ADUser.Enabled){
    # output to report
}
```

Comment: Hey Mathias, sadly that would simply filter out the disabled mailboxes rather than disabled users who have Send As permissions to each of the mailboxes that I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @ItsSimplyEddie Sorry, I misread the original request. I've updated the answer, but you might need to add some handling for groups as well :)

Comment: no worries at all. The new answer did look promising but it don't seem to like Get-ADUser or .Split as a method for some reason.